# What is the theory behind Fresnel's half period zones?

Tags: optics, diffraction

[image]

I was not convinced by exactly how does this work,why do we need to take concentric spheres around point P and how do those spheres cast circular areas on the wavefront?
Why is the radius OM1 and the first sphere originating from P not same?

Comment: Which book is this

Answer (score 1):

Consider the wavefronts (orange) of a plane wave moving in from the left.

[image]

Each point on a wavefront acts as a secondary source - Huygen's construction.

To get to point $F$ the wavelets from point $X$ on the incident wavefront have to travel a distance $XF$.

The wavelets from a point $Y$ on the incident wavefront travel a distance $YF$ and so do not arrive in phase with the wavelets from point $X$.
At point $F$ there is a superposition of these two sets of wavelets.
As long as the path difference between the two sets of wavelets is less than $\frac \lambda 2$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the incident waves the wavelets will superpose constructively ie combine together to give a greater amplitude of the wave at $F$.

If $AF$ and $A'F$ differ in distance by less than $\lambda 2$ then the wavelets which originate from the wavefront $AA'$ will arrive with a phase difference of less than $\frac \lambda 2$ and add together constructively.

Now consider the incident wavefront between $AB$ and consider a point $Z$ producing wavelets.
The distance $ZF$ is larger that $XF$ by at least $\frac \lambda 2$ and so the wavelet originate from $Z$ will be out of phase by greater than $\frac \lambda 2$ and so when they arrive at $F$ will superpose in a destructive manner reducing the amplitude of the resultant wave at $F$.
So that this not happen all waves which would produce a phase difference between $\frac \lambda 2\,(A)$ and $\lambda \, (B)$, and between $\frac \lambda 2\, (A')$ and $\lambda \,(B')$ are removed by making $AB$ and $A'B'$ opaque.

The next zone defined by $BC$ and $B'C'$ is made transparent because all the waves which arrive from that zone are between $\lambda$ and $\frac{3\lambda}{2}$ out of phase with the waves which came directly from $X$ and so will superpose constructively.

The end result is the constructive superposition of wave at $F$.

My diagram is just a section through the zone plate which has rotational symmetry about the line $XF$.

The radii of the circles which define the transparent and opaque zones do not increase in equal increments, just think about the geometry of the situation.

And finally a zone plate can be constructed with the transparent and opaque sections transposed.

Answer (score 0):

It's just commonly known diffraction in 2d. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction) The expression $d\sin(\theta_n)=n\lambda$ in polar symmetry.